# App crashes when launch from recently used app list

Tags: android

I have a special launcher activity with LAUNCHER and MAIN intent-filter which starts my service. When my app starts from the recently used apps list, it is crashes because the service doesn't get started. What is the right way to fix this trouble? Maybe I am experiencing bad architecture of my application?

Comment: we may suggest some solutions if you post the exceptions you are receiving

Comment: Service initialize a lot of global objects... So I understand why it is crashed. All activities could not exist without service. I want achieve to my special launcher activity launches from recent used apps list, only this activity must be entry point in my application always, and no another

Comment: Unfortunately for you this indeed means bad application design, since Android supports multiple app entry points. You should consider rewriting your application in the Android proper way. And, in the meanwhile, post some code, maybe someone else could give you some piece of advice

Comment: @alex thanks, I don't know what code I can post.. Crashed activity - simple NPE bacause service don't initialize needed objects.. Launch activity only call startService() and finished... May be call startService() in Applciation.OnCreate() ??? I forget why but it is bad way too :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `startService()` in Activity's `onStart()` method. This way, it would be called every time your Activity comes to foreground (including calling from recently used apps list). But remember to follow Activity's life-cycle and stop the Service in `onStop()` method.

Comment: thanks, you suggest call startService() in each activitiy? And my service should not stop if activities closes - it must work always while user don't close it